# $f$ locally bounded, nonnegative, and measurable function integrable iff series $\int_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges absolutely

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f$ is a locally bounded, nonnegative, and measurable function on $[1,\infty)$ and define $\displaystyle \int_{n}^{n+1}f$,  $\,\,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, is it true that $f$ is integrable on $[1, \infty)$ if and only if the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges absolutely?

If so, how would you prove it? I'm thinking the Monotone Convergence Theorem, but I'm not entirely sure how to put it into practice.

In one direction, $f$ integrable implies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges absolutely, I'm thinking the following:

> Suppose $f$ is locally bounded, measurable, and nonnegative on $[1,\infty)$, and also that $f$ is integrable over $[1,\infty)$.
>
> Then, $\int_{1}^{\infty}|f|<\infty$, and define $A:=[n, n+1]$.  Then, $f \chi_{A}=f\vert_{A}$.
>
> Since $\int_{1}^{\infty}|f|<\infty$, $\int_{1}^{\infty}|f|\vert_{A}<\infty$ implies that $\int_{A}|f|< \infty$, and since $\int_{A}|f| = \int_{n}^{n+1}|f| = |a_{n}|$, $sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{n}^{n+1}|f|$.

And that was as far as I got.

Please help. Full proofs preferred.

Comment: Monotone convergence theorem -- great idea.  Try defining $g_n$ so that $g_n(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in [1,n)$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x>n$.  You are getting too good at this stuff for "full proofs."

Comment: @B.S.Thomson, I would be inclined to agree with your assessment of my abilities if I didn't have only 40 minutes to figure this out. In the other direction, it is similar to a problem I've done before, but in the direction where I'm assuming $f$ is integrable, I'm kind of lost. If I let $f(x) = g_{n}(x)$ as you have defined it above, then am I using the Monotone Convergence theorem to pull the limit outside the integral??

Comment: @B.S.Thomson, anyway, $g_{n}(x)$ isn't even increasing, so how can I even apply Monotone Convergence to it??

Comment: Handed in now? Grade A+?

Comment: @B.S.Thomson, handed in, yes. A+ probably not. I still need to figure it all out though in detail. Next week, no classes, so I'll be feverishly studying.

Comment: Good luck.  I hope not feverishly though.  Try a saucer of warm milk.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson hey, it's been a while! I was wondering if you could take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2453786/proof-of-integral-of-a-simple-measurable-function  Also, new name - I used to be Jessy Cat.

Comment: I miss Jessy Cat and don't watch Game of Thrones.  When you get your PhD let us know.