# Proof of integral of a simple measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I need to prove that for $x_{1}, x_{2}, \cdots $ and disjoint $A_{1}, A_{2}, \cdots $, for a simple measurable function $f(\omega) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_{i}I_{A_{i}}(\omega)$, $$ \int f d \mu = \int_{\Omega} f(\omega) d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_{i}\mu(A_{i})$$

And I need to do so by using $$ \sup_{A_{1},\cdots , A_{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\inf_{\omega \in A_{i}} f(\omega) \cdot \mu(A_{i}) = \int f d\mu = \int_{\Omega} f(\omega) d \mu(\omega) = \int_{\Omega}f(\omega)\mu(d\omega),$$

where $(\Omega,\mu)$ is a measure space, and $A_{i}$ is a partition of $\Omega$.

From this last statement, it appears that I need to show $\sup_{A_{1},\cdots , A_{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\inf_{\omega \in A_{i}} f(\omega) \cdot \mu(A_{i}) =\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_{i}\mu(A_{i})$

And since $f(\omega) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_{i}I_{A_{i}}(\omega)$, this becomes a case of needing to show

$$\sup_{A_{1},\cdots , A_{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\inf_{\omega \in A_{i}}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_{i}I_{A_{i}}(\omega)\cdot \mu(A_{i}) =\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_{i}\mu(A_{i}).$$

But I don't know how to do that.

Could someone please help me figure out how to prove this? Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: The sets $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ in the first and the second sentence are not the same, so I suggest you use different symbols for them.  In the first sentence, the sets $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ are given (i.e., _free_) whereas in the second sentence, the sets $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ are _bound_: the supremum is among all partitions $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables).  So, the equation in the third sentence is not correct because its left-hand side does not depend on $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ whereas its right-hand side does.

Comment: @Blackbird okay, I looked at the link, but I don't think this I should terribly helpful in advancing my understanding of how to do the proof.

Comment: Do you see the problem with the equation in your third sentence?

Comment: @Blackbird by third sentence, do you mean "From this last statement, it appears that I need to show $\sup_{A_{1},\cdots , A_{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\inf_{\omega \in A_{i}} f(\omega) \cdot \mu(A_{i}) =\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_{i}\mu(A_{i})$"?  From what you said, the $A_{i}$ on the LHS are bound now, so I'm guessing that this equality is incorrect, but the problem is that I don't know how to make it correct. If I call the ones on he RHS $B_{i}$ instead, I still don't know how I am supposed to proceed.

Comment: Well, that's a start.  You want to show that for the function $f=\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i I_{A_i}$, the supremum of $\sum_{k=1}^n\inf_{\omega\in B_k}f(\omega)\cdot\mu(B_k)$ over all $n$ and all partitions $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_n$ of $\Omega$ is $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i\mu(A_i)$.

Comment: @Blackbird which is what I couldn't figure out how to do in the first place.

Comment: @Blackbird if you could post an answer or help me do THAT, I would be most appreciative.

Comment: You might need to assume $x_i\geq 0$ for all $i$ (or perhaps just assume $x_i=0$ for all but a finite number of the $x_i$).  Else hte integral may not exist (even if we allow it to have infinite value).  Example:  Let $\Omega = [0, \infty)$.  Define $A_n = [n, n+1)$ for $n \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$>  Then define $$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \underbrace{n(-1)^n}_{x_n} I_{A_n}(x)$$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n (-1)^n$ does not exist.

Comment: You can answer your own question to show your current work if you like.

Comment: @Michael I added a comment below, so you can't see where my train of thought is at right now in terms of trying to understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to write down what you know correctly and precisely before you start solving a problem and then think about the meaning of what you want to show.

You want to show that for the function $f=\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i\cdot I_{A_i}$, the supremum of
\begin{align}
   \sum_{k=1}^n\inf_{\omega\in B_k}f(\omega)\cdot\mu(B_k) \tag{$*$}
\end{align}
over all $n$ and all partitions $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_n$ of $\Omega$ is \begin{align}
   \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i\mu(A_i) \;. \tag{$**$}
\end{align}

Now, let us consider a fixed partition $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_n$.
What is the meaning of ($*$)?  Note that ($*$) is the integral of a simple function dominated by $f$.  Namely, for $\omega\in B_k$, let us define $g(\omega)$ to be the infimum of $f$ over $B_k$, that is, $g(\omega)=\inf_{\sigma\in B_k}f(\sigma)$.  Using indicator functions, we can represent $g$ by the formula
\begin{align}
   g(\omega) &:= \sum_{k=1}^n g_k\cdot I_{B_k}(\omega)
\end{align}
where $g_k:=\inf_{\sigma\in B_k}f(\sigma)$.
Then, ($*$) is simply the integral of $g$, that is, $\sum_{k=1}^n g_k\cdot\mu(B_k)$.

In order to show that the supremum of ($*$) is ($**$) you have to show two things:

1. For each parition $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_n$, the value ($*$) is no greater that ($**$).
2. The value ($*$) can be made arbitrarily close to ($**$) by choosing the partition $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_n$ appropriately.  Here, you have to consider three different cases, depending on whether ($**$) is $-\infty$, $+\infty$ or in $(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Now, you can try to see why (1) and (2) are true.  It will help if you think about a concrete example.  Say, consider an example in which $\Omega$ is the real line and choose $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ to be disjoint intervals.  Sketch the graph of $f$ and think about the meaning of the function $g$ for a particular partition $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_n$.  (In your sketch, you may choose $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_n$ to be intevals as well, although in your final proof, they do not need to be intervals.)

Comment: I will try to work through (1) and (2). Is it okay if I have follow-up questions in case I don't figure them out or get stuck on something?

Comment: Sure.  I will probably be online again later today.

Comment: what do you mean $(*)$ is the integral of a simple function dominated by$f$? I thought $f$ was the simple function?

Comment: For intuition (especially on part 2) you might at first simplify the problem to consider a modified problem with $f(\omega) = \sum_{i=1}^M x_i I_{A_i}(\omega)$ (a finite number of terms for some fixed integer $M>0$, rather than an infinite number of terms).  When there are an infinite number of terms that is where you will need to consider the 3 cases as Blackbird describes.

Comment: @Michael what does that have to do with $(*)$ being the integral of a simple function dominated by $f$?

Comment: @ALannister : You are focusing on minor details. Blackbird's answer already explains $g$ is a simple function with integral (*). You can ignore that fact if you want (unless you already know the integral of a finite sum  is the sum of integrals).  You should focus on either the case $x_i\geq 0$ for all $i$, or $x_i=0$ for all but the first $M$ terms. Then (related to Blackbird's part 2) consider a _particular partition_ $\{B_i\}$ corresponding to the existing disjoint $\{A_i\}$ sets. [Of course $\{A_i\}$ does not necessarily cover $\Omega$, so it may not itself be a partition of $\Omega$.]

Comment: @Blackbird so I drew a graph with the $A_{i}$ as intervals along the $x$-axis, and then the function values in each $A_{i}$ are straigh lines (I.e., it's a step function), so on $A_{1}$, it's $x_{1}$, $A_{2}$ it's $x_{2}$, etc. so then, I made the $B_{i}$ also intervals, but smaller ones that overlap with one or more of the disjoint $A_{i}$. Then, if $g_{k}=\inf _{\sigma\in B_{k}}f(\sigma)$, so if $B_{1}$ is contained entirely within $A_{1}$, then shouldn't $g_{1}=x_{1}$? Does it seem like I'm understanding it?

Comment: @ALannister Yes, you are on the right track.  One thing to pay attention to is that there are (countably) infinitely many $A_i$s whereas the partition $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_n$ is finite.  It may simplify things to note that we can assume $A_i$s also form a partition.  (If not, add another set $A_0$ which is the complement of $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ and consider the sequence $A_0,A_1,\ldots$ instead.)

Comment: And by the way, @Michael is right that the sum ($**$) may not converge if there are no constraints on $x_i$s.  As he suggested, you could perhaps focus on either the case that all $x_i$s are non-negative, or the case that at most finitely many of them is non-zero.

Comment: @Blackbird I'm still not sure how to go about handling the cases where $(**)$ is either $\pm \infty$. Can you provide any more details for at least what one of them (either plus or minus infinity) might "look like"?

Comment: Let us make the assumption that $x_i\geq 0$ for each $i$.  Suppose that ($**$) is $+\infty$.  Then, (1) is easy.  To show (2), we must show that ($*$) can be made arbitrarily large, so that its supremum is $+\infty$.  More precisely, we need to show that for every $R>0$ no matter how large, we can find a partition $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_n$ such that ($*$) is larger than $R$.  You could construct such a partition using the sequence $A_1,A_2,\ldots$.  Start by choosing an integer $M$ large enough such that the sum of the first $M$ terms of ($**$) is larger than $R$.